# Pyspark left joins dataframes using incorrect joining key values

Tags: pyspark

I have 2 spark dataframes.
df1 with columns customerid, salary
df2 with column customerid2, education

Example:
df1
| customerid | salary |
|------------|--------|
| C1         | 120    |
| C2         | 90     |
| C3         | 90     |
| C4         | 100    |

df2
| customerid2 | education |
|-------------|-----------|
| C1          | BA        |
| C2          | BS        |
| C5          | PhD       |
| C4          | BS Physics|

I want a new data frame names df_new1 that joins above 2 data frames using following code.
I want to left join df1 with df2 using joining key customerid and customerid2.

```py
df_new = df1.join(df2, on=x[df1.customerid==df2.customerid2],how='left')
```

**Expected Output:**
df_new
| customerid | salary | customerid2 | education |
|------------|--------|-------------|-----------|
| C1         | 120    | C1          | BA        |
| C2         | 90     | C2          | BS        |
| C3         | 90     | NULL        | NULL      |
| C4         | 100    | C4          | BS Physics|

**Current Output:**
df_new
| customerid | salary | customerid2 | education |
|------------|--------|-------------|-----------|
| C1         | 120    | C1          | BA        |
| C2         | 90     | C5          | PhD       | <-- Issue in this line
| C3         | 90     | NULL        | NULL      |
| C4         | 100    | C4          | BS Physics|

Issue is, when I perform a join for some of the records in spark dataframe, it's joining the 2 tables even though the customer ID values are different.

Appreciate a response from this great community on this very rare issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your code.

Comment: df_new = df1.join(df2, on=[df1.customerid==df2.customerid2],how='left').    So, in df_new spark dataframe there are few records where customerid is not matching but pyspark is still joining and showing 2 different customerid and customerid2 values.

Comment: @KalpeshJain Don't include your code as a comment. Please edit your original post to _include_ your code and other details that might help solve your problem.

Comment: @CyanCoding Yes..added the details as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
Taking your data as example it is generating expected output as you posted

>>> columns2 = ["customerid2","education"]
>>> data2=[("c1","BA"),("c2","BS"),("c5","phD"),("c4","BS Physics")]
>>> rdd2=sc.parallelize(data2)
>>> df2=rdd2.toDF(columns2)

>>> columns = ["customerid","salary"]
>>> data=[("c1","120"),("c2","90"),("c3","90"),("c4","100")]
>>> rdd=sc.parallelize(data)
>>> df1=rdd.toDF(columns)

>>> df_new = df1.join(df2,df1.customerid == df2.customerid2,"leftouter")
>>> df_new.show()
```

+----------+------+-----------+----------+
|customerid|salary|customerid2| education|
+----------+------+-----------+----------+
|        c1|   120|         c1|        BA|
|        c4|   100|         c4|BS Physics|
|        c3|    90|       null|      null|
|        c2|    90|         c2|        BS|
+----------+------+-----------+----------+

can you check whether any of the Data does not contains leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: I have already removed the spaces at both the sides in joining keys.  Yes, i understand it comes for few records but not all the records in my case.   Not sure why it's happening, seems very rare one.